# How to "downgrade" C# Decimal data type to some arbitrary number of decimal places?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I have a database table with a field defined in a very simplified form like that

```
CREATE TABLE Product
(
    ProductId INT,
    Price SMALLMONEY
)
```

I have a LINQ entity framework query that in it's simplified form goes something like:

```
Iqueryable query = from Product in testDB.Products
        select new
        {
            Price = Product.Price
        }
```

The problem is that this produces unexpected and unwanted behavior describes in my other post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32610246/aspxtextbox-how-to-make-it-to-use-displayformatstring-correctly

I have researched this and I have concluded that this unwanted behavior is due to my query result returns field Price as Decimal with 4 decimal points. This is understandable as SMALLMONEY is stored in database with 4 decimal points of precision.
If I reduce the number of decimals everything works ok. Something like this in this trivial example

```
Iqueryable query = from Product in testDB.Products
            select new
                {
                    Price = 1.12m;  // Decimal literal with 2 decimals
 }
```

So I thought it would be sufficient to round this number to two decimals and I will be ok.

```
Iqueryable query = from Product in testDB.Products
                select new
                {
                    Price = Decimal.Round(Products.Price,2) // round to two decimals    
                }
```

WRONG. Somehow the value Price persists the knowledge that it stores 4 decimal points and my web form is messed up.

I took a look at source code for DecimalRound() found at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/decimal.cs

```
[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
public static Decimal Round(Decimal d, int decimals)
{
    FCallRound (ref d, decimals);
    return d;
}
```

This passes argument value by reference, so I guess only the value of argument is changed and not it's inner "meta" data describing precision.

What can I do? How can I downgrade the precision to two decimals.

Comment: "WRONG. Somehow the value Price persists the knowledge that it stores 4 decimal points and my web form is messed up." Please show a short but complete program that demonstrates exactly what you mean. It's very hard to tell just from your description.

Comment: If the type in your DB is `SmallInt` then the type in your entity shouldn't be `decimal`.

Comment: @juharr Sorrry sorry sorry. It is smallmoney. I will correct. I am down on my concentration.

Comment: @JonSkeet I cannot upload the whole project with database aspx files and everything in here. In my other (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32610246/aspxtextbox-how-to-make-it-to-use-displayformatstring-correctly) post I have described funny behavior. But through testing I narrowed it down to this Decimal issue.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you upload your whole project. I was suggesting that you create a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. Those are *entirely* different things. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @jonskeet This is a complete thing that demonstrates the problem. The change in this single line of code makes things behave differently. I do not know how to get the number of stored decimals of data type ot I would create a suitable .net fiddle.

Comment: No, it isn't. It isn't a complete program we can copy, paste, compile and run, nor a suitable ASP.NET equivalent, if you really can't demonstrate it in a console app. You haven't explained what you're actually seeing vs what you expected to see. (We shouldn't have to click on another post to find out what you're seeing.) Until those aspects are present, your question is going to be *much* harder to answer - and less useful to others in the same situation. (I strongly suspect that if you'd posted a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, you'd have had an answer half an hour ago.)

Comment: One point to note - while you're calling `Select` on an `IQueryable`, the projection is going to be performed in SQL. So you might want to check what the SQL is doing. You could always project to a local type, then call `AsEnumerable()`, then perform a further projection in LINQ to Objects, doing the rounding locally.

Comment: @jonskeet Well, to be honest I dont know how to do that. To copy paste a simple demonstrator with aspx file, devx components, database, entity framework. I stumbled on this issue in editform template that behaves erratic. But if I substiutute (see above) a constant value with two decimals (1.12 in exampel above) somehow things work. This makes me conclude that there must something with decimal storage. I would create a simple demo on .net fiddle, but I do not know hot to see how many decimals doed Decimal type store.

Comment: Do you not know how to express what you want to see vs what you actually see any more clearly than "my web form is messed up" either? Surely at the very least you can improve that aspect of the question. You could also try writing a console app with the same query, just writing the results to the console - if that demonstrates the same problem, then you've removed the whole ASP.NET and DevX side of things. A large part of software engineering is diagnosing problems by removing dependencies...

Comment: Is there a way to get a number of decimals in Decimal type. Something like NumberOfDecimal() or GetPrecision() or whatever.

Comment: @jonSkeet It all comes down to this that Decimal.Round(1.0000m,2) is not the same as Decimal.Round(1.00m,2). I am not saying not equal like == operator, but there is something different.

Comment: @f470071: I believe those actually *do* give the same results - but as I said earlier, you're not really calling `decimal.Round` - you're expressing a call which is then translated into SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you're not actually performing the rounding using `decimal.Round`. Instead, you're expressing it in the query which is being translated into SQL.

If you want the rounding to be done in .NET instead, you need to make sure you're using LINQ to Objects - and the easiest way to do that is to call `AsEnumerable`. For example:

```
var results = testDB.Products
    .Select(p => new { p.Name, p.Price })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(p => new { p.Name, Price = decimal.Round(p.Price, 2) });
```

Note that you should make sure you do any ordering, filtering etc *before* `AsEnumerable()`, to avoid it pulling all the results down and filtering locally.

As a side note, while there isn't a simple property to obtain the scale, sign and significand, you can use [`decimal.GetBits(decimal)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.getbits) to obtain the internal representation. This is useful for comparing whether two values are *identical*, and for more details you can consult the documentation as to what each bit means.

Comment: Yes. I have looked at the sql and you were right. my Decimal.Round(Product.Price) gets sqled as ROUND([Project1].[Price], 2) AS [C4] and because the return type of ROUND(DECIMAL(S,P)) is DECIMAL(S,P) I get the same data type as original data. Ok, now I know where i s the root of evil.

Comment: But I am afraid that using AsEnumerable() is not an option as my grid uses dynamic paging, sorting, filtering.....

Comment: @f470071: Then you'll need to find some other way to perform the rounding *after* executing the rest of the query, basically. I'm not familiar with the rendering library you're using, but I'm sure that must be possible.

Comment: What Jon Skeet turned my attention to, was the root of trouble. In short Decimal.Round() in my Iqueryable was transformed to SQL ROUND() which outputs the same DECIMAL(s,p) type as argument. I have fixed that in my web component level. Accepted and upvoted. Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

Without more context all that can be advised is to convert to a different datatype:

```
select new 
{
    Price = (double) Products.Price
};
```

Or a string:

```
select new
{
    Price = Products.Price.ToString("##.00")
}
```

Comment: Converting it to `double` is a horrible idea - it's simply the wrong data type for monetary values.

Comment: If his only intention is to display the data to the user (which will get converted to a JS double somewhere down the line anyway) I see no problem with it. Speaking of the general case you are right, though.

Comment: I think we'll have to agree to disagree. This feels like the kind of thing that ends up causing really hard to diagnose errors way down the road. This should be fixable whilst sticking to the `decimal` type.

Comment: I would like to stick to conceptually correct things too, Yet those workarounds are tempting if you waste a lot of time trying to fix something that defies logic.